# Pipe command in Bash

Tags: bash

Pipe command is showing it's results properly .When i try to use it cat or > it doesn't show the output

i have try to run the command with different spaces but it didn't help

```
 sort spiderman.txt | cat > superman.txt
```

```
 sort spiderman.txt | > superman.txt
```

in the first above code cat is not showing it's output (the cat command is not showing contents of superman.txt ) however if i write is separately  the cat command it's showing the contents

in the second command nothing happens to superman.txt 
ideally it should have replaced all contents of superman.txt and replaced with sorted contents of spiderman.txt but nothing happens.

Comment: `sort spiderman.txt | cat > superman.txt` is awkward, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying simple output redirection you shouldn't pipe (`|`), just redirect (`>`):

```
 sort spiderman.txt > superman.txt
```

If you want to show the content as well as redirect to a file - perhaps what you're looking for is `tee`?

```
sort spiderman.txt | tee superman.txt
```

Description:

> The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.

Comment: Sorry to say but this does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

`> superman.txt` (with no command) is processed as follows:

1. `superman.txt` is opened for writing and truncated
2. The output redirection is removed from the current command.
3. Since there is nothing left, the empty command is treated as having
    run and exited successfully. Nothing actually reads from the pipe
    or writes to `superman.txt`.

`cat` is necessary as a command which *does* read from standard input and writes to standard output.

---

It sometimes seems a little odd to me that more shells don't provide a minimal built-in that simply copies input to output with no frills, to avoid otherwise having to fork and exec `cat`. ( I should say "no" rather than "more", as I'm not aware of *any* shell that does. `zsh` might, if I bothered to search through the documentation to find it.)

(Some shells will optimize away an extra fork when processing a command line; `bash` is not one of them, though. It forks once to create a process for the write end of the pipe, then forks again to run `cat`. I believe `ksh` would simply `exec` `cat` directly instead of unnecessarily forking, in which case a built-in `cat` is less necessary.)